# Function of did

Tags: functions

What is the function of did in this paragraph?

I did get quite a few letters from all over the country..

I tried to search on google about this but I haven't found something useful.

Comment: Please show you effort first, such as a grammar tutorial.

Comment: _Do_ can be used to emphasise another verb. In your sentence, it implies that the speaker was a little surprised to have received so many letters. Sometimes it can indicate a contradiction. "Why didn't you remind me about X?" "I _did_ tell you, but you weren't listening."